# <label>, вложенный элемент формы и порядок отображения элементов

Tags: javascript, html

Есть `<label>` и привязанный к нему `<input type="checkbox">`:

```
checkBox = document.createElement("input");
checkBox.type = "checkBox";

label = document.createElement("label");
label.textContent = "press me!";
label.appendChild(checkBox);
document.body.appendChild(label);
```

В браузере лейбл отображается вначале (слева), а чекбокс в конце. Вопрос: Можно сделать так, чтобы чекбокс шел впереди? Я знаю, что есть еще свойство `label.for`, но оно требует ID элемента, а присваивать каждому чекбоксу ID не хочется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var label = document.createElement("label");
body.appendChild(label);

var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
checkBox.type = "checkbox";
label.appendChild(checkBox);

var labelText = document.createElement("span");
labelText.textContent = "press me!";
label.appendChild(labelText);
```